# Verilog `PATHPULSE$` Syntax

Tags: syntax, verilog, ambiguous-grammar

In reading the Verilog specification, I noticed a peculiar syntactical construct involving specifying path pulses. Specifically, statements in the form

```
PATHPULSE$in_port$out_port = ...;
```

According to the spec, `in_port` and `out_port` can either be identifiers (which includes `\`-escaped identifiers) or identifiers with a `[]`-bracketed range.

Ignoring issues with tokenizing the `PATHPULSE` construct with brackets, there still seems to be a potential ambiguity issue since `$` can be part of normal identifiers. For example, if a module is declared like:

```
module my_mod(
    input foo,
    output bar$baz,
    input foo$bar,
    output baz
);
...
```

Then given a path pulse statement:

```
PATHPULSE$foo$bar$baz = ...;
```

There's no way to determine which `$` separates the input and output ports.

My question is this: is there a better way to tokenize `PATHPULSE` constructs to avoid this ambiguity? Or is this a shortfall of Verilog?

Comment: Is it about the specify blocks which assigns delays to the paths? Maybe you can refer [here](https://www.hdlworks.com/hdl_corner/verilog_ref/items/Specify.htm) about `specify` block.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known shortfall of the PATHPULSE syntax. See https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=1050. It's best to avoid using $ in an identifier.

Escaped identifiers are not a problem because they are always terminated with a space.